# How to check if JAVA code (that persists in database) completed properly or terminated abruptly?

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, kotlin, mybatis

I have a service that persists some data in SQL Server. 2 of the fields that i am persisting are named

`is_valid` that is just a safety check, in case we need to invalidate the current service run (and whatever data it persisted in DB) in future.

Another field is `end_execution_time`, which is the time when the current service ended.

When i start the service, i have `is_valid=0` and `end_execution_time=NULL`. When the run completes (succesfully), i have `is_valid=1` and `end_execution_time=GETDATETIME()`. Now, here is my concern

I have 3 scenarios that might happen ->

1. Service Run fails. Code knows that run failed. So we update in DB that `is_valid = 0`. `end_execution_time` remains NULL.
2. For some reason, Run fails, and code also stops working (sort of like a Ctrl-C in terminal) . `is_valid` originally has a value of 0. it still remains zero. `end_execution_time` remains NULL.
3. some run is active. right now is_valid is 0. `end_execution_time` is NULL.

IN FUTURE, HOW DO I CHECK WHETHER CURRENTLY SOME SERVICE IS IN-PROGRESS, OR HAD TERMINATED ABRUPTLY?

There is no way to distinguish between the 2nd and 3rd case. Please help me out. I'm using Spring-Mybatis and Java/Kotlin

Comment: `For some reason, Run fails,` You need to actually drive that error to root cause.  Nothing just fails for no reason.

Comment: I mean lets say a host goes down....problems can happen anytime for weird reasons...

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the service code, here are some things you can do to help with distinguishing between the 2nd and 3rd case.

1) Check for long running service calls and expire them. Assume that calls over some interval (1 minute?) are dead. Implement this using a start time and a datediff.

2) Use the FINALLY part of try/catch/finally to update the database on service call failures.

3) Implement the service call as an async service call as described here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Continuations#Jetty_6_Continuations I know you aren't using Jetty, but it sounds like you need a timeout on the service call that updates the database.

I don't have an idea about how to address your problem without modifying code.

Good luck!

Comment: Ya code can be edited. i dont have an issue with try catch finally. my concern revolves around abrupt system failure, where the latter part of the code never worked. the concern for checking long running service calls/failed calls is how do I differentiate scenario 2 and scenario 3 in question?

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically you can catch that does process ended abruptly or not. However concern here is that you are dealing with three states. In my opinion you either need intermediate state of is_valid and end_time or extra column in database which will identify current state

For example :

State 1 :

```
            success 

            is_valid = 1

            end_time = time
```

State 2 : unsuccessful but process did not ended abruptly

```
          is_valid = 0 

          end_time = null
```

State 3 : unsuccessful but process and ended abruptly

```
          is_valid = -1 // just an example

          end_time = -1  // just an example
```

Comment: even if i have an intermediate state of is_valid, i wont be able to update it in case of abrupt program failure. It will be in the same state as it was running in. Even an extra column will remain in the same state as the one while running.

Comment: begin 
             save   -> is_valid=-1 , end_time = -1

success ->   update -> is_valid=1 , end_time = end time

unsuccessful -> finally { update -> is_valid=0 , end_time = null }

abrupt end of the service will leave is_valid = -1, end_time = -1 in the db

Which implicitly says that your service has updated the db is_valid=-1 , end_time = -1 
but after that it was neither successful nor unsuccessful

Comment: As its known that you can not update anything after abrupt failure. You need to back trace it. So original state defines something bad has happens in between